# python3 datetime object behavior issue when incrementing and using in a list

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I am calculating orbital positions of  satellites using PyEphem, but the problem I am having manifests apart from the actual PyEphem code, so I have simplified the example, excluding any pyephem code.  However, for the sake of project context... in each loop, the incremented calcDT is used to compute satellite pass details for that new calcDT, and it is all to be stored in a list for later analysis and plotting, retreiving values that I expected I had actually appended to the list.

There are three datetime objects involved.  A rise time, a set time, and a calc time, riseDT, setDT and calcDT respectively.  The riseDT and setDT should not change at all. They do not. The calc_DT is stepped with each loop.  The calcDT is then equality checked with the setDT to see if the pass is ended.  I've used .id() to see (and show) what memory locations are being referenced when and where, showing apparently that 'in the list in the loop' calcDT reverts to referencing the memory location of the riseDT 'object (and its value)' used to first create calcDT, when I actually want it to be referencing a completely new calcDT incremented 'value'.

Here is the full code that demonstrates the problem.  Particularly note that in the last three result blocks, the riseDT and calcDT values in the list are the same (they shouldn't be), even though the standalone var versions are appropriately different and correct. :

```
import datetime


riseDT = datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 13, 5, 30, 0, 0)
setDT = datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 13, 5, 30, 1, 500000)
calcDT = riseDT
stepS = 0.5

fullPassList = []

print('==============================================')
print('riseDT before loop :', riseDT)
print('riseDT id()        :', id(riseDT))
print('calcDT before loop :', calcDT)
print('calcDT id()        :', id(calcDT))
print('note that both are referencing the same memory')
print('==============================================')
print('riseDT before loop :', riseDT)
print('riseDT id()        :', id(riseDT))
print('attempt to force an independent calcDT created')
print('with the value only of riseDT by using the')
print('.replace method with no change specified.')
calcDT = riseDT.replace()
print('calcDT before loop :', calcDT)
print('calcDT id()        :', id(calcDT))
print('It worked before the loop, but issues inside it?')
print('==============================================')
print('Still alright after putting them into a list?')
fullPassList.append(riseDT)                       # index   [0]
fullPassList.append(stepS)                        # index   [1]
fullPassList.append(calcDT)                       # index   [2]
print('riseDT before loop, in list :', fullPassList[0])
print('riseDT id()        : ', id(fullPassList[0]))
print('stepS  before loop, in list :', fullPassList[1])
print('stepS  id()        : ', id(fullPassList[1]))
print('calcDT before loop, in list :', fullPassList[2])
print('calcDT id()        : ', id(fullPassList[2]))
print('==============================================')
print('==============================================')

while calcDT <= setDT:    # should show 4 result sets

    print('riseDT inside loop :', riseDT)
    print('riseDT id()        :', id(riseDT))
    print('calcDT inside loop :', calcDT, ' alright as a var')
    print('calcDT id()        :', id(calcDT))
    print('Looks alright here, but put them in a list ...')
    print('- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ')

    # pyephem code start
    #  does stuff but irrelevant to issue
    # pyephem code end

    print('Still alright after putting them into a list?')
    # No.  calcDT goes back to referencing the memory location of riseDT
    # when calcDT is put into a list and then accessed in the list.
    fullPassList.append(riseDT)                       # index   [0]
    fullPassList.append(stepS)                        # index   [1]
    fullPassList.append(calcDT)                       # index   [2]
    print('riseDT inside loop, in a list :', fullPassList[0])
    print('riseDT id()        : ', id(fullPassList[0]))
    print('stepS  inside loop, in a list :', fullPassList[1])
    print('stepS  id()        : ', id(fullPassList[1]))
    print('calcDT inside loop, in a list :', fullPassList[2], ' NG in list?')
    print('calcDT id()        : ', id(fullPassList[2]))
    print('----------------------------------------------')

    calcDT += datetime.timedelta(seconds=stepS)
```

Here are the results of running this code, showing the issue.  I can duplicate the problem consistently on a Toshiba L775 Ubuntu 18.04LTS (without a venv) and python 3.6.5, and several raspberry pi 3B+ Raspbian Stretch with locally  compiled python 3.7.0 in a venv.  Results can be seen to be consistently undesired, here, run on the rpi 3B+:

```
==============================================
riseDT before loop : 2018-11-13 05:30:00
riseDT id()        : 1990840856
calcDT before loop : 2018-11-13 05:30:00
calcDT id()        : 1990840856
note that both are referencing the same memory
==============================================
riseDT before loop : 2018-11-13 05:30:00
riseDT id()        : 1990840856
attempt to force an independent calcDT created
with the value only of riseDT by using the
.replace() method with no change specified.
calcDT before loop : 2018-11-13 05:30:00
calcDT id()        : 1990671560
It worked before the loop, but issues inside it?
==============================================
Still alright after putting them into a list?
riseDT before loop, in list : 2018-11-13 05:30:00
riseDT id()        :  1990840856
stepS  before loop, in list : 0.5
stepS  id()        :  1990697152
calcDT before loop, in list : 2018-11-13 05:30:00
calcDT id()        :  1990671560
==============================================
==============================================
riseDT inside loop : 2018-11-13 05:30:00
riseDT id()        : 1990840856
calcDT inside loop : 2018-11-13 05:30:00  alright as a var
calcDT id()        : 1990671560
Looks alright here, but put them in a list ...
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Still alright after putting them into a list?
riseDT inside loop, in a list : 2018-11-13 05:30:00
riseDT id()        :  1990840856
stepS  inside loop, in a list : 0.5
stepS  id()        :  1990697152
calcDT inside loop, in a list : 2018-11-13 05:30:00  NG in list?
calcDT id()        :  1990671560
----------------------------------------------
riseDT inside loop : 2018-11-13 05:30:00
riseDT id()        : 1990840856
calcDT inside loop : 2018-11-13 05:30:00.500000  alright as a var
calcDT id()        : 1990671608
Looks alright here, but put them in a list ...
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Still alright after putting them into a list?
riseDT inside loop, in a list : 2018-11-13 05:30:00
riseDT id()        :  1990840856
stepS  inside loop, in a list : 0.5
stepS  id()        :  1990697152
calcDT inside loop, in a list : 2018-11-13 05:30:00  NG in list?
calcDT id()        :  1990671560
----------------------------------------------
riseDT inside loop : 2018-11-13 05:30:00
riseDT id()        : 1990840856
calcDT inside loop : 2018-11-13 05:30:01  alright as a var
calcDT id()        : 1990669160
Looks alright here, but put them in a list ...
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Still alright after putting them into a list?
riseDT inside loop, in a list : 2018-11-13 05:30:00
riseDT id()        :  1990840856
stepS  inside loop, in a list : 0.5
stepS  id()        :  1990697152
calcDT inside loop, in a list : 2018-11-13 05:30:00  NG in list?
calcDT id()        :  1990671560
----------------------------------------------
riseDT inside loop : 2018-11-13 05:30:00
riseDT id()        : 1990840856
calcDT inside loop : 2018-11-13 05:30:01.500000  alright as a var
calcDT id()        : 1990479624
Looks alright here, but put them in a list ...
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Still alright after putting them into a list?
riseDT inside loop, in a list : 2018-11-13 05:30:00
riseDT id()        :  1990840856
stepS  inside loop, in a list : 0.5
stepS  id()        :  1990697152
calcDT inside loop, in a list : 2018-11-13 05:30:00  NG in list?
calcDT id()        :  1990671560
----------------------------------------------
```

I understand that there are a few 'odd behaviors', some hidden, of the python language interpreter, compared to some other languages.  I am trying to understand them while also getting the results desired.  Other odd behaviors documented here, as an example.

https://github.com/satwikkansal/wtfpython

I do not have the experience and knowledge to authoritatively endorse that link, but I have experienced some of those issues.

I have been programming simple python3 for a year with many successful projects.  I have encountered some of these python oddities and successfuly learned how to work around or with them.  This one has me persistently puzzled.

I freely admit I am missing something probably ridiculously easy, possibly having become 'blind' to what is right in front of me, so I am asking for help to see that simple solution that will keep my code very easily readable, and working as expected, even if that requires correcting my expectations.

Thank you in advance.

update:
This has been answered and is marked as such.  Embarassing error, but I leave it here as an example of the importance of another set of eyes reviewing one's code before taking too much time trying every possible remedy while still missing the simple problem.  Now and then one may become locked in on where the problem surely must be, and consequently become blind to where it actually is, and quite simple.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is quite long, if possible you could try to shorten it a bit to get faster an answer. Thanks!

Comment: I shall work on it David, but the code and results seem important to keep as is.  This is already a tremendous shortening of everything I have tried in the last week.

Comment: Two things to keep in find. Lists are mutable, so if you have multiple references to one and change it in one place, it will be reflected in the other place. Two, timedelta is immutable, so the in-place operator `+=` doesn't actually modify in place, it produces a new object.

Comment: @keith. yes. I want a new calcDT created, and its new value put in the list,  each loop iteration, but it is putting the old calcDT and value in the list, the one from before the loop... The value of the riseDT is persistently re-appearing, taking over what was the new incremented value in the var version of calcDT before that new correct calcDT is appended to the list.  IOW, the print displays the new calcDT with the correct incremented DT, but the list.append() method becomes(?) blind to the new calcDT value and instead grabs the old reference and value and appends THAT to the list.  Huh...

Comment: @ Keith, thank you. That was helpful information for the subject in general, and should be a good reminder for anyone who comes upon this post.  See my comment to Trebuchet under his 'answer'.  I got a good laugh at myself out of this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short Answer

The reason why `id()` is spitting the same integer out every time is because, you're indexing the **same** index ***every time***.

You keep adding to `fullPassList` without clearing it. Only the *first three* elements are accessed in your code.

As your list grows with new `calcDT`, the code indexing it doesn't keep up. It just stays put at `fullPassList[2]`. And of course, the object there stays the same...

## Long Answer

### The Culprit

Let's take a look at the portion of code after `calcDT = riseDT.replace()`

```
print('calcDT before loop :', calcDT)
print('calcDT id()        :', id(calcDT))
print('It worked before the loop, but issues inside it?')
print('==============================================')
print('Still alright after putting them into a list?')
fullPassList.append(riseDT)                       # index   [0]   ## OK
fullPassList.append(stepS)                        # index   [1]   ## OK
fullPassList.append(calcDT)                       # index   [2]   ## Yep
print('riseDT before loop, in list :', fullPassList[0])           ## All these are fine.
print('riseDT id()        : ', id(fullPassList[0]))
print('stepS  before loop, in list :', fullPassList[1])
print('stepS  id()        : ', id(fullPassList[1]))
print('calcDT before loop, in list :', fullPassList[2])
print('calcDT id()        : ', id(fullPassList[2]))
print('==============================================')
print('==============================================')

while calcDT <= setDT:    # should show 4 result sets

    print('riseDT inside loop :', riseDT)
    print('riseDT id()        :', id(riseDT))
    print('calcDT inside loop :', calcDT, ' alright as a var')
    print('calcDT id()        :', id(calcDT))
    print('Looks alright here, but put them in a list ...')
    print('- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ')

    # pyephem code start
    #  does stuff but irrelevant to issue
    # pyephem code end

    print('Still alright after putting them into a list?')
    # No.  calcDT goes back to referencing the memory location of riseDT
    # when calcDT is put into a list and then accessed in the list.
```

and then the moment of truth

```
    fullPassList.append(riseDT)                       # index   [0] ## Nope
    fullPassList.append(stepS)                        # index   [1] ## Nope
    fullPassList.append(calcDT)                       # index   [2] ## Ditto
```

These will push the datetimes to indices 3, 4, 5 on the first loop; 6, 7, 8 on the second; and so on. So consequentially,

```
    print('riseDT inside loop, in a list :', fullPassList[0])  ## oops?
    print('riseDT id()        : ', id(fullPassList[0]))
    print('stepS  inside loop, in a list :', fullPassList[1])  ## oops?
    print('stepS  id()        : ', id(fullPassList[1]))
    print('calcDT inside loop, in a list :', fullPassList[2], ' NG in list?')  ## oops!
    print('calcDT id()        : ', id(fullPassList[2]))  ## oops!!!
    print('----------------------------------------------')
```

The code is repeatedly querying for `fullPassList[2]`. This will *give the same result each time*. Not what you intended. :-)

There you go, bug detected.

### Proposed Solutions

There are a several ways you could do to fix this. You *only* want *calcDT*

#### `list.clear()`

Throw in a `fullPassList.clear()` somewhere in the loop. Maybe after `# pyephem code end` and before you do `.append()`?

This will let the newly added datetimes to be correctly referenced in `fullPastList[0]`, `fullPastList[1]`, and `fullPastList[2]`.

#### `list[-index]`

You can still keep your old datetimes and access your newly added datetimes by simply indexing the third-last element `fullPastList[-3]` for `riseDT`, the second-last element `fullPastList[-2]` for `stepS`, and the last element `fullPastList[-1]` for `calcDT`. This may be more handy as it holds on to previous values.

But you mentioned that `riseDT` and `stepS` won't change... which leads me to speculate

#### Option #3

In your while loop, just before the end of your code, comment out two lines and...

```
# fullPassList.append(riseDT)  ## You already appended these before the loop.
# fullPassList.append(stepS)   ## Since they'll be constant, it'll be a waste of space
                               ## to append these.

fullPassList.append(calcDT)    ## You still want to append this since it will change
                               ## on each loop.

print('riseDT inside loop, in a list :', fullPassList[0]) ## This is fine, this will
print('riseDT id()        : ', id(fullPassList[0]))       ## still access `riseDT`
print('stepS  inside loop, in a list :', fullPassList[1]) ## This is also fine.
print('stepS  id()        : ', id(fullPassList[1]))

## Change these to access the LAST element, using list[-1]
print('calcDT inside loop, in a list :', fullPassList[-1], ' NG in list?')
print('calcDT id()        : ', id(fullPassList[-1]))
print('----------------------------------------------')
```

So all you'll be needing to add to the list is the `calcDT`. I'm sure that your code is **much much more** complicated than this. But hopefully, this answer outlines the culprit behind the head-scratching and turmoil you've been faced with.

Comment: Thank you kindly TrebuchetMS.  Here's what happened.  A very distracted week!  Could not get 5 minutes of concentrated effort at the keys, without being called away, except the post.  The calling program is thousands of lines.  This was to be only a function,  begun seperately due to distractions.  The calling program was to do the list of lists.  Very embarassing, but I am not above laughing at myself!  Goes to show the importance of another set of eyes -- and the power of distractions every 5 minutes, when working on a complex project.  Now working fine. btw, I have built a small trebuchet.

Comment: At first I doubted myself. Is it really that simple a bug.  But I'm glad that you could strip the large project down to a bare minimum which still allowed for debugging. There was effort shown, at the very least. Have a great week! :-)

Comment: It may be partly because I took this approach, during so many distractions, to break out this code, that I had the problem. If I had continued working in the larger code, this may never have happened, since the list of lists boilerplate was already setup. But then, who can tell?  Other times, breaking out the code was beneficial.  Either way, it is done now.  All is good. Lesson? Sometimes it is better to take a good break than to completely change an approach ... sometimes.  And perhaps better yet, when possible, have another set of eyes take a look at the problem.  Thank you.

Comment: Additionally, overall, it was a bit more than 'that simple a bug'.  I will summarize soon by writing an answer that references the importance also of what was in your answer.  SImply here, without example code, using .clear() caused much grief so that a new list was not made to add to the big list of lists.  Instead, the code kept using the same memory locations to append to the list of lists so that the final list of lists was only the values of the very last list that was appended to it.

Comment: By using = [] to empty the list after the append to the list of lists, and before adding new values, did what was intended, not actually emptying the previous list, but making a new instance of a list with the same intended name, while keeping the previous intended historical values in the list of lists.  The example I will post soon, as an answer, will make this much clearer.